# Best way to slim down my code on onclicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I am not great at javascript/jquery for the most part but I know how to get some software to work. But my issue is that I have a whole bunch of

```
$("body").on("click", "button#thisid", function(event) {
    //do stuff here
});
```

There are alot of the on clicks that use jquery post and get functions but they all have tiny and simple differences that i need to have get sent through. I dont want every single button to have an onclick event but I am not sure how to bind the event to a large list of items that need to have it attached to.

I have been trying to come up with some way to slim all these down but I want to have the best approach instead a whole bunch of crash and fails. So I am reaching out to people who know more than me in order to lead me in the correct path.

Please help

Comment: The best way would be to work out what functionality is synonymous between the multiple clicks. If there's similar functionality, you could target a **class** instead of an ID. Can you please post the rest of your code?

Comment: impossible to tell you how to improve it with info given.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I was thinking along those lines but didn't know if it was the most efficient way. Unfortunately I cannot post the code, though i would love to in order to help become better. Also I was not sure if i needed to think like a plugin or just a class type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your elements are dynamically injected, you will need to apply the click handler to an element that always exist on page load:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", "button.target", function() {
    console.log($(this)[0].id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="1" class="target">One</button>
<button id="2" class="target">Two</button>
```

In the above example, the click handler is applied to `document`, and triggers whenever a button element with the class of `target` is clicked, running the code inside the function.

To combine the `.get()` and `.post()` functions, you'll have to find synonymous data. Keep in mind that you have access to `$(this)`, so you can extract the relevant ID if need be :)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A nice way I find is having a one line for each button like so:

```
$('#model').on('click', openModel());
$('#openDropdown').on('click', openDropdown());
$('#shoppingCart').on('click', shoppingCart());
```

And then defining each of these functions:

```
function openModel() {
    // Stuff here
}

function openDropdown() {
    // Stuff here
}

function shoppingCart() {
    // Stuff here
}
```

So instead of writing the function as a parameter, I find it neater to just do it separately and call it like above.

Comment: He doesn't want to have a click handler for each element.

Answer (score 0):

I dont exactly get what you want to do...
But the $("body") is the jquery selector which defines on which elements your listener will be bound to.

So if you want to create a listener for more different elements the probably easiest solution is creating a class like "listenedElement" which you give to every element you want the listener to react to and write write the selector like this

```
$('.listenedElement').on( "click", function() {});
```

If you just look for click listeners this one looks pretty nice as well:
https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: some of my content is dynamic so the buttons are not always rendered on page load. So i listen to the body for the button click. I also dont want to attach all kinds of data tags (data-id, data-type) to every button in order call specific events. Do you see another way around this?